# Spring Mvc TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with a Spring Mvc app and try to use `Hibernate` as ORM. The app structure is provided,

[image]

The `webapp` folder is provided below,

[image]

The `MySQL database ERM` is provided below,

[image]

I use `Maven` for the dependency management and `JNDI` for the database connection. The `database-context.xml` file is provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="mobi.puut.database">

    </context:component-scan>

    <beans profile="production">

        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource"
                         expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        </jee:jndi-lookup>


        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>

            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>mobi.puut.entities</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
              class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
        </bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

The `POJO` files are inside the entities directories and formed of the `User` and the `Status` classes.

The `User` class is provided below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 45, message = "Name must be between 5 and 45 characters.")
    private String name;


    public User() {

    }

    public User(@Size(min = 5, max = 45, message = "Name must be between 5 and 45 characters.") String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(int id, String name) {

        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (getId() != user.getId()) return false;
        return getName().equals(user.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + getName().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The `Status` class is provided below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;


    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
//    private int user_id;
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "balance")
    private float balance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 90, message = "Address must be between 5 and 90 characters.")
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "transaction")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 90, message = "Transaction history must be between 5 and 90 characters.")
    private String transaction;

    public Status() {

    }

    public Status(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Status(User user, @NotNull float balance, @NotNull @Size(min = 5, max = 90, message = "Address must be between 5 and 90 characters.") String address) {
        this.user = user;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Status(User user, @NotNull float balance, @NotNull @Size(min = 5, max = 90, message = "Address must be between 5 and 90 characters.") String address, @NotNull @Size(min = 5, max = 90, message = "Transaction history must be between 5 and 90 characters.") String transaction) {
        this.user = user;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.address = address;
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

//    public Status(@NotNull int user_id) {
//        this.user_id = user_id;
//    }

    public Status(float balance, String transaction, String address, int user_id) {
//        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.address = address;
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

    public Status(int id, int user_id, float balance, String address, String transaction) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
//        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.address = address;
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

//    public int getUser_id() {
//        return user_id;
//    }

    public float getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

//    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
//        this.user_id = user_id;
//    }

    public void setBalance(float balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setTransaction(String transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Status)) return false;

        Status status = (Status) o;

        if (getId() != status.getId()) return false;
        if (Float.compare(status.getBalance(), getBalance()) != 0) return false;
        if (!getUser().equals(status.getUser())) return false;
        if (!getAddress().equals(status.getAddress())) return false;
        return getTransaction().equals(status.getTransaction());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + getUser().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (getBalance() != +0.0f ? Float.floatToIntBits(getBalance()) : 0);
        result = 31 * result + getAddress().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getTransaction().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Status{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", transaction='" + transaction + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I wrote the source code for mapping the statuses with the user,

```
public class StatusRowMapper implements RowMapper<Status> {

    @Override
    public Status mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(rs.getString("name"));

        Status status = new Status();

        status.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        status.setBalance(rs.getFloat("balance"));
        status.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        status.setTransaction(rs.getString("transaction"));
        status.setUser(user);
        return status;
    }
}
```

The class and method I wrote to get all the statuses,

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Component("bitcoinWwallet")
public class BitcoinWalletDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Status> getAllWalletStatus() {

        Criteria crit = session().createCriteria(Status.class);
        return crit.list();
    }

}
```

When I make call to get all the statues in the `JSP` from the controller, I get the error,

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing 

failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

If I comment out the `@Transactional` on the top of the class `BitcoinWalletDAO`, I get the database connection error from the error handler,

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
public String handleDatabaseException(DataAccessException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();
    return "error";
}
```

Previously, I use `SQL` to get all the statues from the db and that worked fine,

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public List<Status> getAllWalletStatus() {
      final String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM status";

      return jdbc.query(sqlString, new RowMapper<Status>() {

        public Status mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Status status = new Status();

            status.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            status.setBalance(rs.getFloat("balance"));
            status.setTransaction(rs.getString("transaction"));
            status.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
     //                status.setUser_id(rs.getInt("user_id"));
            return status;
        }

    });
}
```

[image]

I can provide more info if required. How to solve the issue?

Comment: you need a transaction so @ transactional is required. IT can be also used at method level too. How ever if you do not want to use @transactional then you can go for openconnection() and closeconnection()

Comment: Okay, how to solve the problem in hand?

Comment: In the transactionManager refer to sessionFactory than dataSource.